# Permanent browser cache using ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, security, caching, service-worker

I am designing a JavaScript secure loader. The loader is inlined in the `index.html`. The goal of the secure loader is to only load JavaScript resources are trusted. The contents of `index.html` are mostly limited to the secure loader. For security purposes, I want `index.html` (as stored in cache) to never change, **even if my website is hacked**.

How can I cache `index.html` without the server being able to tamper with the cache? I am wondering if `ServiceWorker`s can help. Effectively, the `index.html` would register a service worker for fetching itself from an immutable cache (no network request is even made).

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to achieve? Once user visits `index.html`, the `html` `document` itself and resources linked from `index.html` should not be changed?

Comment: What you seek to achieve -if possible- would ALSO prohibit you from ever updating said method for recurring visitors while it would offer no protection at all for new visitors.  Seems far too many drawbacks for the limited advantage you might achieve.

Comment: @swa66 The secure loader would have logic to be updatable in a controlled fashion.

Comment: And what would prevent the hacker "owning" the website from using the update mechanism ?

Comment: I don't really follow, what are you trying to protect for security purposes. Index.html would reside on the client ones downloaded from the server. This would then be cached by the browser if the page is given long live expiry dates and long etag.

Comment: @swa66 Cryptographic signatures for which only the legitimate website owner has.

Comment: How about creating an app shell?, an app cache will cache index.html and load index.html from cache.

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail: Is it possible to create a permanent app shell?

Comment: Once page is loaded it create a permanent cache, but i am ot sure what happens on page reopen, what you are looking for is cache : immutable attribute , which is only available in firefox. setting cache: immutable prevents browser from hitting server request for that resourse, so in your case if you set cache: immutable to index.html then browser wont hit server for index.html. Immutable cache feature is only available on firefox not on chrome.

Comment: So you have a cryptographically signed component permanently loaded in the client that needs a secret key to be updated. Consider this: hacker breaks in on your site, installs his own tool signed with his own key to download onto all new visitors. How are you ever going to get those to update back to your tool ? You won't have the attacker's secret key to sign an update ...

Comment: With all due respect, </disclaimer> you do not design a website considering it is going to be hacked and you will lose control of it each and every day after your 4pm tea. You just don't. Reason of your question rather *smells like* you are going to hack some website and put a content there, and you do not want legitimate admin to be able to change it afterwards. Again, forgive me if it is not the case but this smells plain maleficent to me.

Answer (score 4):

in chrome you can use [FileSystem API](http://caniuse.com/#search=Filesystem)

http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-filesystem-api-create-files-store-locally-using-javascript-webkit.html this allows you to then save and read files from a sand-boxed file-system though the browser.

As for other support it's not been confirmed as an addition to the HTML5 specification set yet. so it's only available in chrome.

You could also use the [IndexDB](http://caniuse.com/#search=IndexDB) system this is supported in all modern browsers.

you can use both these services inside a Service Worker to manage the loading and manage of the content however i have to question why would you want to you prevent your self from ever updating your index.html

Comment: Note that the Filesystem API (formal title: [File API: Directories and System](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/)) is obsolete and no other browsers have any plans to ever implement support for it. The specification itself has been demoted to a W3C “Note” with a warning in bold: **Work on this document has been discontinued and it should not be referenced or used as a basis for implementation.** So while it’s fine to use for the case where somebody might only care about having something that works just in Chrome, they should not expect to see it working in any other browsers, ever.

Comment: BTW this is why we don't trust W3C on HTML5 they standardised something that should not have been standardised updated on the 11th of January 2017, https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/ " Other browsers (at this time: Microsoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox) are starting to support subsets of Chrome’s APIs and behavior."

Answer (score 4):

This design goal of "secure javascript loading"/TOFU is typically associated with javascript crypto and browser secrets (e.g. Cyph, Mega), so I'll include some relevant recommendations along the way.

You're in dangerous territory. There are many dragons.

**Option 1: Implement [feross/infinite-app-cache](https://github.com/feross/infinite-app-cache) to permanently cache the app in the browser**

Here's the least amount of code required to achieve a TOFU web app in all browsers.

index.html:

```
<html manifest="manifest.appcache">
```

manifest.app cache:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/manifest.appcache
/index.html
/script-loader.js
```

And make sure you serve the manifest with a content type of "text/cache-manifest".

Note: This standard is deprecated, however it will take some years before browsers disable this feature.

**Problem**: If an attacker (who has already hacked your server) can trick your users into visiting a URL not in the app cache, they can serve arbitrary code to extract/use browser secrets etc.

**Solution**: User input cannot be intercepted by a malicious page on the same domain (unless you do something really silly), so encrypt any browser secrets using a user-supplied password and dchest/scrypt-async-js.

Another thing to consider is the cached contents of a page CAN be extracted by the malicious page simply by using AJAX - so you HAVE to use user input, not just a random token rendered to the page.

**Option 2: Extend the above solution with HPKP Suicide and a Service Worker**

Implement [HPKP Suicide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KK41OLrbY5o) to permanently "bake" the app into the browser by bricking the user's connection to the server.

If (and only if) you have implemented HPKP Suicide, service workers are now safe to use because the enforced max-age of 24 hours has no effect if the browser can't re-download the service worker.

index.html or script-loader.js:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  });
}
```

service-worker.js:

```
var files = [ 
  '/',
  'index.html',
  'script-loader.js'
].map(file => new Request(file))

self.addEventListener('install', () => {  
  caches.open('cache')
    .then(cache => {
      files.map(file => {
        fetch(file)
          .then(response => cache.put(file, response))
          .catch(err => console.error(err))
      })
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  var url = e.request.url.split('#')[0]

  if (!files.filter(file => file.url === url).length) {
    return e.respondWith(new Response('Not Found', { status: 404 }))
  }

  return e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(cachedResponse => {
      if (cachedResponse) return cachedResponse

      return Promise.all([
        caches.open('cache'),
        fetch(e.request.clone())
      ]).then((results) => {
        var cache = results[0]
        var response = results[1]

        cache.put(e.request, response.clone())

        return response
      })
    })
  )
})
```

**Important note**: Without HPKP Suicide, using a service worker is LESS secure than infinite app cache because the service worker has a max-age of 24 hours, even if your server's cache directives set a higher age. Using service workers will also completely disable app cache. It's a waste of time trying to achieve this with service workers if you haven't implemented HPKP Suicide.

**Discussion**

- HPKP suicide has lost the guarantee of permanence in Chrome as they have recently implemented a max-max-age of 60 days (see issue #523654 for discussion)
- I strongly recommend you use TweetNaCl.js for all browser crypto: it takes effort to use incorrectly and unless you are encrypting large files the performance difference with WebCrypto is insignificant

Comment: Service Workers don't actually fall back to App Cache, even if it looks like they do - the App Cache console messages still display, but the functionality is completely turned off. Even returning a network error from the Service Worker doesn't force app cache to be triggered. So service workers won't work without HPKP Suicide because there is no other way to prevent them from recycling every 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache), which can save the responses of your requests (all kinds of requests - html pages, api requests, images). But note, that it's currently supported only in Chrome and Firefox.

On that page is also example how to use it with `fetch`